# In SML, is it possible to define an alias for a pattern?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Let's say I have the following datatype

```
datatype mytype = Foo | Bar | Baz
```

and want to write a function like the following

```
fun myfun ((Foo|Bar), (Foo|Bar)) = something
|   myfun (Baz, _) = somethingelse
|   ...
```

Is there a way to create an alias for the pattern `Foo|Bar`, so that I can write it out once and avoid repeating myself?

Comment: You could design a very lightweight preprocessor which allows you to use simple abbreviations which are replaced by their values prior to compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is plain "no", unfortunately. The notion of "abstract patterns" or "views" has been suggested many times, but it is a tricky space, and no proposal has ever been fully satisfying (and that applies to other languages like Ocaml or Haskell as well).